# Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to use this code to make a deep nested reactive form which I've found in this site: https://stackblitz.com/edit/deep-nested-reactive-form?file=app%2FformBuilder-way.ts

But Its showing this error:

```
Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.
```

What is wrong in this code bellow ?

```
const control = <FormArray>this.survey.get('sections').controls[j].get('questions');

const control = <FormArray>this.survey.get('sections').controls[i].get('questions').controls[j].get('options');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to access it this way: `['controls']` and not `.controls`.

I had this error once, when I run `ng build --prod`

```
const control = <FormArray>this.survey.get('sections')['controls'][j].get('questions');
```

Comment: You can also do it with a single `get` call: `const control = this.survey.get(\`sections.${j}.questions\`) as FormArray;`